# How to call a function when a particular select option is chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JS and am currently trying to set up a form, where when a certain country is selected as a select option, it will cause a second select drop-down to appear through the use of display="block" to display="none".

Earlier within this project I was able to accomplish a similar thing where a certain radio input causes a text input to appear through the before mentioned display principle. I achieved this easily using another forum.

After attempting to use the same principles for my current problem and that method not working, as I'm pretty sure the terms i was using don't apply, I begun looking through more forums and have tried two methods that seem to apply best for my problem, however both do not work.

```
**HTML**
<select name="country" id="country" required onchange="showState()">
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected" hidden>Country</option>
  <option value="australia" id="australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="england">England</option>
</select><br>
<select name="state" id="state">
<option>'s...
</select>
```

```
**JavaScript method 1**
function showState() {
  var australia = document.getElementById("australia");
  var state = document.getElementById("state");

  if (this.options[this.selectedIndex] == australia){
    state.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    state.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```
**JavaScript method 2**
function showState() {
  var theValue = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  var state = document.getElementById("state");

  if($(this).find('option:selected').val() === 'australia') {
    state.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    state.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

I expected the last method as it was from a question very similar to mine, but all it produced was the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: The browser is unable understand what the $ variable is. Have you included jQuery in the app?

Comment: @Sreeram Thanks, as I am new to JavaScript in general I forgot to link it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jquery, you can do that in a simpler way. Of course, don't forget to import the Jquery library.

```js
function showState() {
  if ($("#country option:selected").val() === "australia") {
    $("#state").show()
  }
  else {
    $("#state").hide()
  }
}
$("#country").change(showState)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country" id="country" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected="selected" hidden>Country</option>
  <option value="australia" id="australia">Australia</option>
  <option value="england">England</option>
</select><br>
<select name="state" id="state">
  <option>Queensland</option>
  <option>Victoria</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, that also worked, and in a slightly simpler manner. May ask, does this work without the use of `(el)` and `this` because its defining the id's without the use of `var`'s?

Comment: The variables are really redundant. There is no need to use them at all, since one should usually use variables only if they are used more than once.